# How to use File.foreach in production ? (using heroku run rails c)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-console

I'm executing the following code in the development mode in my rails console.

```
query_results = File.foreach('Query Results.csv').map { |line| line.split() }
```

This grabs each line of my 'Query Results.csv' and pushes it into an array. When I try to run the same code in production mode, I get an error:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - Query Results.csv

What's the best way to achieve the same result in production? PS: I'm using Heroku, so I'm accessing my console like this:

```
$ heroku run rails c --app=app-name
```

Comment: You just need to make sure that Heroku finds your file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your files commited and pushed to Heroku and then access them using `File.foreach(Rails.root.join('Query Results.csv'))` if your file is in the root of the project.